# Can't install build-essential on Ubuntu Jaunty 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.04, g++

Here's my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 9.04 _Jaunty Jackalope_ - Release i386 (20090420.1)]/ jaunty main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jaunty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jaunty partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security multiverse
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, which results in *E: Couldn't find package build-essential*

and

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential` which results in several *Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/multiverse Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]* and 
*W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]* errors

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ubuntu version is no longer supported by Canonical. Standard archive servers no longer host packages for Jaunty, as Ubuntu (non-LTS) versions are only supported for 18 months, and Ubuntu LTS are only supported for 3 years.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS:

> We produce a new Ubuntu Desktop and
>   Ubuntu Server release every six months
>   [diagram below]. That means you'll
>   always have the latest and greatest
>   applications that the open source
>   world has to offer. Ubuntu is designed
>   with security in mind. **You get free
>   security updates for at least 18
>   months on the desktop and server.**

Comment: I realized this actually, so I'm moving up to 10.04 which I think should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may use one of miriades unofficial mirrors. Try this search

http://www.google.com/search?q=intitle%3A%22Index+of+%2Fubuntu%2Fdists%22+jaunty

select one on your favor. 
I'm use http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/, so lines in sources.list seems like

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates multiverse
```